# Delete Item from another Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to build a simple todo-app using asp.net mvc. 
my app has 2 models:
 1 for the lists (ToDoLijst.cs)

```
namespace OnsLijstje.Models
{
    public class ToDoLijst
    {
        [Key]
        public int LijstId { get; set; }
        public string Titel { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LijstItem> LijstItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and 1 for the items (lijstItems.cs)in the list.

```
namespace OnsLijstje.Models
{
    public class LijstItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int LijstItemId{ get; set;}
        public int LijstId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }

        public virtual ToDoLijst TodoLijst { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now I have a view where the lists are shown with their items and this works fine. This is the Index.cshtml of the ToDoLijst views.

```
<div class="container lijsten">
@foreach (var lijst in Model.Lijsten)
{
    <div class="col-lg-5 lijst">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11">
                <h3>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lijst.Titel)
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "ToDoLijsten", new { id = Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lijst.LijstId) }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-actions no-color pull-right">
                        <button type="Submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-default btn-close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model.LijstItems)
        {
            if (item.LijstId == lijst.LijstId)
            {<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "LijstItems", new { id = item.LijstItemId})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
}
```

I can delete the lists as a whole. Bud now I want to be able to delete the items 1 by 1 from the list. I use the code below to do this bud it brings me to the view 'Dele' of the LijstItems views.
Is there a way I can get the items deleted directly

this is the code I use:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "LijstItems", new { id = item.LijstItemId})"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

Thnx

Comment: Can you post the code from your controller?

Comment: Your delete action does not need to return a view, it could just return a simple JSON confirmation message that could be displayed by the client after an ajax post.

Answer (score 1):

what i understood from your question is that you want to delete the record without going to the delete page:

to do this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.LijstItems)
        {
            if (item.LijstId == lijst.LijstId)
            {<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-11">
                    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <input type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteButton" data-id="@item.LijstItemId"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        }


<script>
$("#deleteButton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var id=$(this).data("id");
     $.post('@Url.Action("DeleteDirectly","YourController")',new {id:id},function(data){
         if(data.status){
            alert("Delete succeeded!");             
         }
         else{
            alert("Delete failed!");
         }
     });
});
</script>
```

in your controller

```
public JsonResult DeleteDirectly(int id)
{
     // you do the delete from database
     // if deleted successfully from database then write the following code
     return Json(new {status=true});
     // if deletion was failed for any reason, then return the following code
     return Json(new {status=false});
}
```

hope it will help you